# Am I using '&&' incorrectly?

Tags: c, operators

I have a problem in which I have to take 3 words from user as input. What I have to do with that input:

1. In first word, all vowels should be replaced by '$'
2. In second word, all consonants should be replaced by '#'
3. And third word should be converted to uppercase

Here is the code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char first[20], second[20], third[20];
    int i, j;

    char vowel[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    printf("Enter first word: ");
    scanf("%s", first);

    printf("Enter second word: ");
    scanf("%s", second);

    printf("Enter third word: ");
    scanf("%s", third);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(first); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (first[i] == vowel[j])
                first[i] = '$';
        }   
    }
    printf("Final strings are: \n");
    printf("%s", first);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(second); i++) {
        if (second[i] != 'a' && second[i] != 'i' && second[i] != 'o' && second[i] != 'u' && second[i] != 'e');
           second[i] = '#';
    }
    printf("%s", second);
    printf("%s", strupr(third));
}
```

NOTE: All 3 words should be concatenated on output screen

Output:

```
Enter first word: kali
Enter second word: kali
Enter third word: kali
Final strings are:
k$l$####KALI
```

But the expected output is:

```
Enter first word: kali
Enter second word: kali
Enter third word: kali
Final strings are:
k$l$#a#iKALI
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think your problem is just that you have a `;` at the end of your `if`, which causes the `if` to end. Get rid of the semicolon, and wrap the part under it in curly braces. Never omit curly braces unless you have a good reason.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah! that was the only problem.

Comment: Good. Seriously though, use `{}`. That wasn't the problem here, but they may have made the problem more obvious, and omitting them can cause bugs later.

Comment: @dave That was far from the only problem, but it was that that caused the error you are describing. ;)

Comment: regarding: `if(second[i] != 'a' && second[i] != 'i' && second[i] != 'o' && second[i] != 'u' && second[i] != 'u');`  I doubt that you wanted to check for `u` twice, however, the code does need modification to check for the (sometimes vowel) `y`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  (Those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input)  This avoids any possibility of overflowing the input buffer and the resulting undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) honor the right page margin (usually column 72 or 80).

Comment: the check for a vowel fails to check for the letter `e`.  Also, need to check for upper case of the same letters

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("%s", strupr(third));`  The `stdout` stream is buffered.  So the data will not be actually displayed until a '\n' is output or a input function is called or `fflush( stdout )` or the program exits.  Suggest ending each format string with: '\n'

Comment: OT: regarding: `for(i = 0; i < strlen(second); i++){`  this calls the function: `strlen()` on every iteration.  and a string is always terminated with a NUL byte.  Suggest: `for(i = 0; second[i]); i++){`

Comment: @Carcigenicate the reason I omitted the curly braces was it was just a single line statement following `if` but now I understood it was not good practice.

Comment: @dave Even for cases where you only have a single statement, you need to be careful. The problem is when you modify the code later. What if you add another statement after the existing one, not noticing that there aren't any curly braces? Using curly braces from the start is an easy way to avoid an entire type of error from happening; and costs you only a second of typing. The more you can prevent future problems from happening, the better.

Comment: @user3629249 your comments are really informative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a silly mistake in this statement:

```
    if (second[i] != 'a' && second[i] != 'i' && second[i] != 'o' && second[i] != 'u' && second[i] != 'u');
       second[i] = '#';
```

You added an extra `;` at the end of the `if` line, making the test useless and the following statement `second[i] = '#';` execute unconditionally.

You should break such long expressions on multiple lines, avoid redundant tests and use `{` and `}`

```
    if (second[i] != 'a' && second[i] != 'i' && second[i] != 'o' && 
        second[i] != 'u') {
        second[i] = '#';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of problems with your code. If you turn on compiler warnings you'll see this:

```
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic-errors b.c
b.c:32:109: warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
  ...!= 'i' && second[i] != 'o' && second[i] != 'u' && second[i] != 'u');
                                                                        ^
b.c:32:109: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
b.c:37:18: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strupr' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("%s", strupr(third));
                 ^
b.c:37:18: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%s", strupr(third));
            ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
            %d
b.c:20:18: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
      'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(first); i++){
               ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
b.c:31:18: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
      'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(second); i++){
               ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
5 warnings generated.
/tmp/b-8f1874.o: In function `main':
b.c:(.text+0x22a): undefined reference to `strupr'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If you google the warning messages you'll get good hints about what to do about them. The warning about the semicolon that makes the `if` statement having an empty body is what causes your problems.

Another problem is that you don't check the return code of `scanf` to see if the read was successful. It will return the number of successful reads.

Avoid using `strupr`. It is a deprecated non-standard function.

Comment: To add to problems: `scanf("%s", first);` is like `gets(first)` potential to overwrite array.  Better to use `scanf("%19s", first);` - something my compiler warns of

Comment: @Broman I really didn't understand *you didn't check the return code of scanf to see if the read was successful*, can you explain a bit in your answer?

Comment: @dave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967715/using-scanf-to-check-input-parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
char first[20], second[20], third[20];
int i, j;

char vowel[5] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

printf("Enter first word: ");
scanf("%s", first);

printf("Enter second word: ");
scanf("%s", second);

printf("Enter third word: ");
scanf("%s", third);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(first); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (first[i] == vowel[j])
            first[i] = '$';
    }   
}
printf("Final strings are: \n");
printf("%s", first);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(second); i++) {
    if (second[i] != 'a' && second[i] != 'e' && second[i] != 'i' && second[i] != 'o' && second[i] != 'u') // You mistakenly put a semicolon here
       second[i] = '#';
}
printf("%s", second);
printf("%s", strupr(third)); }
```